# C# Combobox Selected.Index = -1 not working

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

It should reset the Combobox to no value, Combobox is in the same panel, but the code sets the index to 0 which is the first value of the data binded list.
It works on the second click though... ON the first click it sets the index to 0, on the second to -1.

```
        if (((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Count() > 0)
        {
           foreach(ComboBox C in ((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList())
            {
                if(C.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    C.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: in the `foreach` `C` is a `combobox` so use that in the if instead of `((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().First()`

Comment: Start by storing the control in a separate variable, stepping through your code and inspecting whether your foreach and if actually execute.

Comment: Why are you using `foreach` on a `list` of `comboboxes` when you than take `.First()` instead of `C`?

Comment: From the documentation for ComboxBox.SelectedIndex: `To deselect the currently selected item, set the SelectedIndex to -1. **You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item.**`

Comment: @MatthewWatson - but that would apply to binding the SelectedItem property to something, not to binding the DataSource.

Comment: I added the loop minutes ago and forgot to change the linq to just c.SelectedIndex.... still not working properly

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Start a new Project add just a Listbox and a Button. Convince us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for answers...in the end I solved the issue with a workaround. The problem was, that button of the code above needed two clicks to set index to -1.
On the first click it moved to 0 and on the second to -1. I dont know why tho...Another problem was i had a index changed event on combobox and i wanted to fire it only once - not twice.
I solved the problem this way...

```
        if (((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Count() > 0)
        {
           foreach(ComboBox C in ((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList())
            {
                if(C.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    C.SelectedIndexChanged -= this.ComboBox_Promo_SelectedIndexChanged;
                    while (C.SelectedIndex != -1)
                    {
                        C.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                    C.SelectedIndexChanged += this.ComboBox_Promo_SelectedIndexChanged;
                    this.ComboBox_Promo_SelectedIndexChanged(C, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try adding a dummy first item to your ComboBox to act as a placeholder.

This way you can deselect simply using `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Just be sure not to interpret this item in the ComboBox as a real item anywhere.

Also, try:

```
ComboBox.ResetText();
ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Or:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
```